# Simplest gradle project with local jar files

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to build a simple project with the following structure

```
Project
├── build.gradle
├── fileToRead.json
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── java
│           ├── driver
│           │   └─ helloJSON.java
│           └── dataHandler
│               └─ handler.java
└── libs
    ├─ javax.json-x.xx.xxx.jar
    └─ ....jar
```

The build.gradle I am trying to build with is;

```java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'driver.helloJSON'
    }
}
```

Now it *will build* however whenever I try to run `java -jar ./build/libs/Project.jar` I get
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/Json`
...

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.Json`

What is going wrong? I know it is not an issue with my code as I am trying to migrate this project from an ant build which builds and runs perfectly fine. I have tried looking online but no examples seem to be simple **and** use local jar files. Please help.

BTW trying `./build/scripts/Project` just shows me to run `Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...] ...`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the following works.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'driver.HelloJSON'
        attributes("Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
}
```