# How to make jar from a master jar in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, build.gradle, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to create a jar file via gradle. I have the java source code located in the folder and one jar file named master.jar i followed this post
[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725436/simplest-gradle-project-with-local-jar-files]**(Link)

but the jar file I got was very much less in size around 10kb but the size of the jar which i get via netbeans is 40kb also when I try to execute the jar file it shows an error that could not find the class file.

Could not find or load main class com.robin.roh.QuickRouteJobScheduler

i think its compilation error do i need to change anything else in my file?

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

// Define the source directory
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/com/robin/roh/QuickRouteJobScheduler']

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.robin.roh.QuickRouteJobScheduler'
        attributes("Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
}
```

Gradle shows build successful.. but when i run that jar it is showing main class not found on terminal.

I want to use the jar files on libs folder to create the QuickRouteJobScheduler.jar i can create it with netbeans but want to use gradle for cicd pipeline on bitbucket

I just want that my jar is created by using the jars on the libs folder anyother simple method too is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Always stick to the **original** documentation. StackOverflow solutions may become deprecated over time. Therefore, follow the [**Gradle DOCs**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_dependency_management_overview):

1. Add your directory (in this example: **libs**) with JARs to your repository

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs '/path/to/libs/directory'
    }
}
```

2. Declare the actual dependency within this JAR

```
dependencies {
   classpath group: 'my-jar-group', name: 'my-jar', version: '1.0'
}
```

If you don't know group and/or version, you may use a simplified dependency:

```
dependencies {
   implementation name: 'my-jar'
}
```

3. Compile your Project

If you don't declare any actual dependency, then your library will be excluded by Gradle to keep your resulting JAR as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/com/robin/roh/QuickRouteJobScheduler']
```

This seems misconfigured, how I am reading this you are using a package structure `com.robin.roh` if that is the case, this should work better

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
```

Comment: I tried this but still same result the jar size is only 11kb and also it Could not find or load main class com.robin.roh.QuickRouteJobScheduler  the manifest has the name of main class